# German character "ü"> not displayed in the Homepage

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding

In this [website](https://cuna-women.ch/) I am facing a text issue: in the Homepage where this text is *"ÜBER CUNA Cuna ist mehr als ein schöner Coworking Space..."* my client can't display the "Ü" properly.

He display it like a normal "U" (using Safari on Mac).

How is possible to fix it?

I tried to write it also with `&uuml;` without any results.

**Info: On my Mac (but also Windows and iOS) I don't have this problem**

This is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="homeAboutUs js-uni-animated">
<h3 class="js-about-two-title">ÜBER CUNA</h3>
```

For the charset I'm using `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

**EDIT: I just realized that it happen also on iPad but as soon you scroll down the character is displayed correctly**

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use IEC_8859-15 instead of utf-8

Comment: @CagCak i tried also this but nothing... :/

I just realized that it happen also on iPad but as soon you scroll down the character is displayed correctly